# Show two sigma fields is equal, without finding the fields?

Tags: measure-theory

Given $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and the sets on X: $A_1=\{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4,5\},\{1,6\}\}$ and $A_2=\{\{1,4,5\},\{2,3,6\},\{4,5,6\}\}$, show that $\sigma(A_1)=\sigma(A_2)$ without finding the $\sigma(A_1)$ and $\sigma(A_2)$?

I feel quite lost on this question, as I cannot think of any way of showing this, without finding the $\sigma$-algebra of both sets on X?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could perhaps prove $A_1\subseteq\sigma(A_2)$ and $A_2\subseteq\sigma(A_1)$

Comment: @saulspatz Would that not require that I find $\sigma(A_1)$ and $\sigma(A_2)$?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.   Show that each element of $A_1$ is an element of $\sigma(A_2)$ by expressing it in terms of the elements of $A_2.$

Comment: @saulspatz Am I doing it right, if I write: $\{1,2,3\}$ must be an element of $\sigma(A_2)$ as $\{4,5,6\}^c=\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for the help, @saulspatz! :)